# AngularJS: binding ng-model to input[type=file] raises 'no longer usable' exception

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Using this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ngTest</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular
            .module('app', [])
            .controller('Main', ['$scope', function($s) {
                $s.data = {
                    level1: {
                        level2: {
                            elements: [{
                                name: 'item1'
                            },{
                                name: 'item2'
                            },{
                                name: 'item3'
                            },{
                                name: 'item4'
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                };
            }]);
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="Main">
    <div ng-repeat="item in data.level1.level2.elements">
        <input type="file" ng-model="item.name">
    </div>
    <pre>{{data}}</pre>
</body>
```

Will raise this error:

```
Error: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.
```

Error fades as soon as you change `type="file"` to `type="text"`. Any idea how to get around this? Im going to write a directive that will listen to the `change` even on the input, upload given file and assign it's value to bound model. But I this error prevents me doing so. Last couple of days costed me quite some hair. Any input on the matter would be much appreciated.

Comment: not sure what you expect to do by pre-populating a file input. WHat good would it do? You don't have the original file object

Comment: not pre-filling the input, just setting the binding to the model. However, I must admit that it gave me an idea to create a wrapper element and add binding to it, instead the input itself

Comment: well when you set `ng-model` and already have a value for that scope property you are essentially populating an input value...which coucln't work on a file input

Comment: I understand. But, are you able to give an advise how could I solve this problem? So that the file uploaded through the input (it's name actually), could get bound to a model?

Comment: if it was me I would output it as text with button(s) for changing it or deleting it or whatever you need. Need better idea of what goals are

Comment: afaik ng-model doesn't work on input file. If you are looking for file upload with angular have a look at angular-file-upload plugin: https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload light-weight with support for upload (for html5 and non-html5 browsers), progress, cancel/abort, and drag&drop. It's a bit tricky to get the upload work in angular. It uses regular $http to send the file

Answer (score 2):

For a single input I simply use

```
<input ng-model="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().upload(this)" type="file">
```

Then I get access to a fileList in my controllers function and send it to a fileReader e.g.

```
$scope.upload = function(el) {
  console.log(el.files);
};
```

I extended it for case of the ng-repeat, so you could check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yCMiRs4u2ret2yC47SNg?p=preview)